# How do you deserialize arrays within formdata json in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, ajax, json.net

I need to take a viewModel and populate a formData with files. I am using a library similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-form-data. However, I am not able to parse the flattened format with JsonConvert on the backend .net side. Is there another way de-serialize json from this format?

Here is sample code I wrote in LinqPad.

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
    'Email': 'james@example.com',
    'Roles': [
      {
        Name:'User',
        Id:1
      },{
        Name:'Admin',
        Id:2
      }]
    }";

    string formDataJson = "{ \"Email\":\"james@example.com\", " +
        "\"Roles[0][Name]\":\"User\"," +
        "\"Roles[0][Id]\":1," +
        "\"Roles[1][Name]\":\"Admin\"," +
        "\"Roles[1][Id]\":2}";

    Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
    Account accountFromFormData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(formDataJson);

    Console.WriteLine(account.Roles.First().Name);
    Console.WriteLine(accountFromFormData.Roles.First().Name);
}

public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This fails because the array is not de-serialized.